# Cannot query GSI in DynamoDb in Kotlin SDK v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am working with DynamoDb using Kotlin.

I am currently using:

```kotlin
implementation platform("software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.17.91")
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:dynamodb'
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:dynamodb-enhanced'
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:sts'
```

I have a simple table with one GSI name `by-users-gsi`.

```bash
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name forum --region us-east-1 --endpoint-url http://localhost:800


{
    "Table": {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "AuthorId",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "PartitionKey",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "SortKey",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "TableName": "table-name",
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "PartitionKey",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "SortKey",
                "KeyType": "RANGE"
            }
        ],
        "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",

        ......

        "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
            {
                "IndexName": "by-users-gsi",
                "KeySchema": [
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "AuthorId",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    },
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "SortKey",
                        "KeyType": "RANGE"
                    }
                ],
                "Projection": {
                    "ProjectionType": "ALL"
                },
                "IndexStatus": "ACTIVE",
                ......
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Both the table and the index have a composite primary key:

- Table: PartitionKey and SortKey
- GSI: AuthorId and SortKey

The problem is that I am trying to query the GSI by the following pseudo-expression:

```
AuthorId="author_id" and SortKey BETWEEN "value_1" and "value_2".
```

Translating it to Koltin. I am using the `DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient`:

```kotlin
val table = client.table('table-name', TableSchema.fromBean(AnyItem::class.java))

val authorIdValue = "author_id"
val value1 = "value_1"
val value2 = "value_2"

val value1Key = Key.builder()
    .partitionValue(authorIdValue)
    .sortValue(value1)
    .build()

val value2Key = Key.builder()
    .partitionValue(authorIdValue)
    .sortValue(value2)
    .build()

val betweenCondition = QueryConditional.sortBetween(value1Key, value2Key)

val query = QueryEnhancedRequest
    .builder()
    .queryConditional(betweenCondition)
    .build()

val results = table
    .index("index-name")
    .query(query)
    .awaitFirst()

// Whatever ......
```

But it is throwing me the following error:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException: Query condition missed key schema element
```

I googled it and is related to not being adding conditions to the Index's PrimaryKey (PK + SK). However, both conditions are defining:

```
.partitionValue(authorIdValue)
```

I understand it should infer the Index's Partition Value, not the table's.
I also tried to do a `FilterExpression` but didn't work too.

Any clue what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I tried to query against the partition key (without sort filter)

```kotlin
val authorIdValue = "author_id"

val value1Key = Key.builder()
    .partitionValue(authorIdValue)
    .sortValue(value1)
    .build()

val partitionCondition = QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(value1Key)

val query = QueryEnhancedRequest
    .builder()
    .queryConditional(partitionCondition)
    .build()

val results = table
    .index("index-name")
    .query(query)
    .awaitFirst()
```

But got the same error

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException: Query condition missed key schema element
```

Answer (score 1):

You never pass the value of the partition `author_id` key to the function:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.pagination.sync.SdkIterable;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.*;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.*;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.Page;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.QueryConditional;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.QueryEnhancedRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;

import java.util.List;

public class QueryBetween {

    static DynamoDbClient client = DynamoDbClient.builder()
            .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
            .build();

    static DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
            .dynamoDbClient(client)
            .build();

    static DynamoDbTable<Movie> moviesTable = enhancedClient.table("Movies", TableSchema.fromBean(Movie.class));

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        QueryConditional condition = QueryConditional.sortBetween(Key.builder()
                .partitionValue(1958)
                .sortValue("1920")
                .build(), Key.builder()
                .partitionValue(1958)
                .sortValue("1950")
                .build());

        QueryEnhancedRequest request = QueryEnhancedRequest.builder()
                .queryConditional(condition)
                .scanIndexForward(false)
                .build();

        SdkIterable<Page<Movie>> movieWithName = moviesTable.index("my-index").query(request);

        movieWithName.forEach(page-> {
            List<Movie> allMovies = page.items();
            for( Movie myMovie: allMovies){
                System.out.println(myMovie.getTitle());
            }
        });
    }

    @DynamoDbBean
    public static class Movie {

        public String creationTime;
        public String title;
        public Long year;

        public Movie() {

        }

        @DynamoDbPartitionKey
        @DynamoDbSecondaryPartitionKey(indexNames = {"my-index"})
        public Long getYear() {
            return year;
        }

        public void setYear(Long year) {
            this.year = year;
        }

        @DynamoDbSortKey
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        @DynamoDbAttribute("release_date")
        @DynamoDbSecondarySortKey(indexNames = {"my-index"})
        public String getCreationTime() {
            return creationTime;
        }

        public void setCreationTime(String creationTime) {
            this.creationTime = creationTime;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: .keyEqualTo(...) returns an EqualToConditional class which does not have a .sortBetween(...) function.

Comment: Ah sorry, you suggested doing .sortBetween(...) after .partitionValue(...). However, partitionValue(...) returns a Key.Builder which does not have a .sortBetween(...) method. It only provides a .sortValue(..)

Comment: Updated my answer after testing code

Comment: Thanks for the updating. However, isn't that the same approach I tried? I also built two keys with partition and sort values which I used to build the QueryConditional.

Comment: Can you please share the current error you are seeing, I have tested my example with no issue. The one thing I see on yours is that you set the index to `index-name` instead of your actual index name `by-users-gsi`

Comment: Yes, in the question I've used dummy values to make it simpler but I am using the correct index in my code. The error is software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException: Query condition missed key schema element. 

Did you perform your tests in a table or in an index?

Comment: I updated the question to show another test I did.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my code to show you the full working example.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Does it work for you if you use "Title" (or any other new property) as the GSI partition key? I see you are using the same PK for the table and the index.

Comment: BTW, the .query method is returning a SdkPublisher, not a SdkIterable. Al least in my SDK bom version 2.17.91

Comment: Oh I just realized what I was doing wrong :,) I will edit the question in a few moments. Now I am struggling with the SdkPublisher but that's another problem. Thanks a lot for the help!!!

Comment: [Query](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/DynamoDbTable.html#query(software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.QueryEnhancedRequest)) returns a PageIterable which is a child of SdkIterable which I use in my example. Yes, the same query works if I change the partition key to one which is not in the base table.